# IntelliJ intention not working

Tags: intellij-idea

I have the intention to replace a String by a StringBuilder enable, and the intention power pack plugin is there. IntelliJ inspects and tells me the String should be a StringBuilder, but it doesn't trigger the intention. Is there a setting I'm missing to enable the intentions? (I'm expecting the intention to kick in and refactor my code)

Comment: Do you mean that if you put a caret on the problematic place and press Alt+Enter, you don't get an intention action to fix it? Can you attach a screenshot showing the list of intentions you get in this menu?

Comment: No, the other way around: I get only an inspection, no intention. I worked with other versions of IntelliJ that suggested the replacement and did it for me.

Comment: Do you still have it enabled: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2752840/screens/snap1875-1343165922.png ?

Comment: Yes. I had verified that, and I verified again just now, and it is enabled.

Comment: Here is what I get on Alt+Enter: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2752840/screens/snap1876-1343168483.png.

Comment: Yes, I do not see the "Replace..." lines on Alt+Enter.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14358/discussion-between-crazycoder-and-frank)

Comment: Here is a snapshot of what I see: https://www.dropbox.com/s/swa9c7qptcw8onq/IDEA%20intention.png